# Spark - Read csv file with quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark, double-quotes

We have the following in a csv file:

```
DI_SEQUENCE_NUMBER;DI_OPERATION_TYPE;MANDT;SPRAS;MVGR2;BEZEI;SRC_SYSTEM;LOAD_DATE;ODQ_CHANGEMODE;ODQ_ENTITYCNTR
76;"I";"220";"E";"200";"SAUGNAPF:BX75P:30/60M.FILT;G3/8""AU1/8"";"D16";"20231017T114626";"C";1
77;"I";"220";"E";"201";"COMPOTS AND FRUIT DRINKS";"D16";"20231017T114626";"C";1
```

Row 76 is causing the problem, we can't find the right options to read correctly. The part that's causing the issue is "SAUGNAPF:BX75P:30/60M.FILT;G3/8""AU1/8"". The original text from system were this csv file is generated is SAUGNAPF:BX75P:30/60M.FILT;G3/8""AU1/8".

We tried with:
option("quote", """)
option("escape",""")

but no luck

We tried with:
option("quote", """)
option("escape",""")

We expect to have this as an output

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

`quote` and `escape` options don't seem to be working in this case. I read the data without any option which show column value like:

> "SAUGNAPF:BX75P:30/60M.FILT;G3/8""AU1/8""

To remove opening and closing quotes I used regexp_replace.

```
spark.read.csv(sep=";", header=True, path=<file_path>) \
     .withColumn("BEZEI", f.regexp_replace("BEZEI", "^[\"]|[\"]$", ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to escape the double quote when setting the options:

```
.option("quote", "\"")
.option("escape", "\"")
```

If you have data with multiple lines then you'll need to add  `.option("multiline", True)`

If you have an extra space between field values then you should also add

```
.option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)
```

I hope it'll work for you.